# Angular CLI is creating project in my home folder

Tags: angular-cli

Whenever I run `ng new appName` the app is created in `/User/name`, which is my home directory. Any idea why this is happening?

My `~/.angular-cli.json` only has `packageManager: 'yarn'`

Comment: You likely have a package.json file there and that effects the logic of determining if you're within an existing CLI project. Locate that file and remove it.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. I had a `package.json` in my home directory.

Comment: Great to hear, I posted this as an answer for others to find in the future, please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have a package.json file there and that effects the logic of determining if you're within an existing CLI project. Locate that file and remove it.